# Getting javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed while reading mailbox using IMAP with OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-integration, imap

We're using OAuth2.0 for reading mailboxes with IMAP protocol. The token has the expiry of 1 hour. Once we started our application, my application is able to read mailboxes for the first 1 hour only. after that, it started giving **org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed**.

Later, by going through source code, I came to know about java mail property mail.imaps.forcepasswordrefresh. So, I added this property mail.imaps.forcepasswordrefresh = true to the existing java mail properties map, so that once the existing token expired, Java Mail API will do a call back to my application to get the new token and getting the new token also. but still getting the same javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.

We're using **Spring Integration 4.3.22.RELEASE** and **Java Mail API 1.5.6** and ours is Spring Application, not Spring Boot.

code snippets **before **I make any changes.

Xml bean

```
<bean id="caseImapMailReceiver" class="org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver">
        <constructor-arg index="0"
                         value="imaps://#{emailReceiverConfig.caseFileUser}:#azureADOAuthTokenService.office365AccessToken@#{emailReceiverConfig.host}:#{emailReceiverConfig.port}/#{emailReceiverConfig.fetchFolder}"/>
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>
```

Java props

```
<util:properties id="javaMailPropertiesCaseFile">
        <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imap</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms">XOAUTH2</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class AcmEmailReceiverAdapter
{
    private EmailReceiverConfig emailReceiverConfig;
    private Properties javaMailPropertiesCaseFile;
    private AzureADOAuthTokenService azureADOAuthTokenService;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "mailChannelCaseFile", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "${email.fixed-rate}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "${email.max-messages-per-poll}", errorChannel = "mailErrorChannelCaseFile"), autoStartup = "${email.create.case.enabled}")
    public MessageSource caseMailMessageSource(ImapMailReceiver caseImapMailReceiver)
    {
        caseImapMailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(emailReceiverConfig.getShouldDeleteMessages());
 caseImapMailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(emailReceiverConfig.getShouldMarkMessagesAsRead());
        caseImapMailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailPropertiesCaseFile);
        caseImapMailReceiver.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        return new MailReceivingMessageSource(caseImapMailReceiver);
    }

    public EmailReceiverConfig getEmailReceiverConfig()
    {
        return emailReceiverConfig;
    }

    public void setEmailReceiverConfig(EmailReceiverConfig emailReceiverConfig)
    {
        this.emailReceiverConfig = emailReceiverConfig;
    }

    public Properties getJavaMailPropertiesCaseFile() {
        return javaMailPropertiesCaseFile;
    }

    public void setJavaMailPropertiesCaseFile(Properties javaMailPropertiesCaseFile) {
        this.javaMailPropertiesCaseFile = javaMailPropertiesCaseFile;
    }

    public AzureADOAuthTokenService getAzureADOAuthTokenService() {
        return azureADOAuthTokenService;
    }

    public void setAzureADOAuthTokenService(AzureADOAuthTokenService azureADOAuthTokenService) {
        this.azureADOAuthTokenService = azureADOAuthTokenService;
    }
}
```

with the above changes, able to authenticate via OAuth2.0 and able to read for 1 hour. Below are logs.

```
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable forcePasswordRefresh
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true

* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QgBMADEAUABSADEAMwBDAEEAMAAwADEANAAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADEAMwAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
A0 CAPABILITY

* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.

DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=core.test@arkcase.com, password=<non-null-value>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.

A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.

DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
A3 LIST "" inbox
* LIST (\Marked \HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX
A3 OK LIST completed.
```

after 1 hour,

```
* BYE Session invalidated - AccessTokenExpired
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore connection dead
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
A168 LOGOUT
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup done
```

code snippet after I make changes.

Xml bean - **same as above**

Java props

```
<util:properties id="javaMailPropertiesCaseFile">
        <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imap</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms">XOAUTH2</prop>
       ** <prop key="mail.imaps.forcepasswordrefresh">true</prop>**
</util:properties>
```

Configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class AcmEmailReceiverAdapter
{
    private EmailReceiverConfig emailReceiverConfig;
    private Properties javaMailPropertiesCaseFile;
    private AzureADOAuthTokenService azureADOAuthTokenService;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "mailChannelCaseFile", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "${email.fixed-rate}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "${email.max-messages-per-poll}", errorChannel = "mailErrorChannelCaseFile"), autoStartup = "${email.create.case.enabled}")
    public MessageSource caseMailMessageSource(ImapMailReceiver caseImapMailReceiver)
    {
        caseImapMailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(emailReceiverConfig.getShouldDeleteMessages());
 caseImapMailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(emailReceiverConfig.getShouldMarkMessagesAsRead());
        caseImapMailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailPropertiesCaseFile);
        caseImapMailReceiver.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        **caseImapMailReceiver.setJavaMailAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                System.err.println("Generating a new token");
                return new PasswordAuthentication(emailReceiverConfig.getCaseFileUser(),azureADOAuthTokenService.getOffice365AccessToken());
            }
        });**
        return new MailReceivingMessageSource(caseImapMailReceiver);
    }

    public EmailReceiverConfig getEmailReceiverConfig()
    {
        return emailReceiverConfig;
    }

    public void setEmailReceiverConfig(EmailReceiverConfig emailReceiverConfig)
    {
        this.emailReceiverConfig = emailReceiverConfig;
    }

    public Properties getJavaMailPropertiesCaseFile() {
        return javaMailPropertiesCaseFile;
    }

    public void setJavaMailPropertiesCaseFile(Properties javaMailPropertiesCaseFile) {
        this.javaMailPropertiesCaseFile = javaMailPropertiesCaseFile;
    }

    public AzureADOAuthTokenService getAzureADOAuthTokenService() {
        return azureADOAuthTokenService;
    }

    public void setAzureADOAuthTokenService(AzureADOAuthTokenService azureADOAuthTokenService) {
        this.azureADOAuthTokenService = azureADOAuthTokenService;
    }
}
```

with these changes, the logs after 1 hour

```
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBOADIAUABSADEAMQBDAEEAMAAwADEANwAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADEAMQAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=core.test@arkcase.com, password=<non-null-value>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
**Generating a new token**
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBOADIAUABSADEAMQBDAEEAMAAwADIAMQAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADEAMQAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=core.test%40arkcase.com, password=<non-null-value>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
2023-07-07 14:51:33,973 [ERROR] [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:379)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:373)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:727)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:321)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:332)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:354)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6fe2213e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$110036a3.receive(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:112)
    ... 17 more
```

I observed that token whatever the token we got for the first when our application started, the same token is being passed to Java Mail even though we're able to generate a new token with callback method,i.e., **mail.imaps.forcepasswordrefresh = true.**

Please advise if there is anything wrong with the above config.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your `setJavaMailAuthenticator()` is correct approach. Every time the `PasswordAuthentication` is requested from there you may return a new OAUTH token. You probably have to remove credentials from your `imaps://` URL definition.

Comment: Also: Spring Integration `4.3.x` is out of support for years. Consider to upgrade to the latest: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#support

Comment: @ArtemBilan as you said, I passed URL like this, after removing username and password imaps://#{emailReceiverConfig.host}:#{emailReceiverConfig.port}/#{emailReceiverConfig.fetchFolder}. but now I'm getting Auth failed exception from the beginning itself.

Comment: But `caseImapMailReceiver.setJavaMailAuthenticator()` must be used anyway.